# How to use an older version of gcc in Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

In Linux I am trying to compile something that uses the -fwritable-strings option. Apparently this is a gcc option that doesn't work in newer version of gcc. I installed gcc-3.4 on my system, but I think the newer version is still being used because I'm still get the error that says it can't recognize the command line option -fwritable-strings. How can I get make to use the older version of gcc?

Answer (score 10):

You say nothing about the build system in use, but usually old versions of gcc can be invoked explicitly, by something like (this is for an autotools-based build):

```
./configure CXX=g++-3.4 CC=gcc-3.4
```

For a make-based build system, sometimes this will work:

```
make CXX=g++-3.4 CC=gcc-3.4
```

Most makefiles ought to recognise overriding `CC` and `CXX` in this way.

Comment: I don't think that will work because the configure file is just a few statements and doesn't do anything.

Comment: Well then it's probably not built with the autotools. If you gave us more detail we might be able to help.

Comment: This guy will probably be hit several times in the next year as the latest upgrade to Ubuntu 11.04 and gcc-4.5.2 breaks gcc. I had to do this to get gst-ffmpeg to compile. I had to do something like. ./configure --prefix=/usr CC=gcc-4.4. To help searches find this link. here is the compiler error:

Comment: This will probably be hit a ton in the next year. The latest ubuntu upgrade breaks some optimizations with gcc-4.5.2 and to get gst-ffmpeg to compile I had to use ./configure --prefix=/usr CC=gcc-4.4. For searching, here is the error: internal compiler error: in set_jump_prob, at
stmt.c:2319

Answer (score 1):

If editing the configuration/Makefile is not an option, Linux includes a utility called [`update-alternatives`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) for such situations. However, it's a pain to use (links to various tutorials included below).

This is a little simpler - here's a script (from [here](https://lektiondestages.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-and-switching-gccg-versions.html)) to easily switch your default `gcc`/`g++` version:

```
#!/bin/bash 
usage() {
        echo 
        echo Sets the default version of gcc, g++, etc
        echo Usage:
        echo 
        echo "    gcc-set-default-version <VERSION>"
        echo 
        exit
}
cd /usr/bin
if [ -z $1 ] ; then 
        usage;
fi 
set_default() {
        if [ -e "$1-$2" ] ; then 
                echo $1-$2 is now the default
                ln -sf $1-$2 $1
        else 
                echo $1-$2 is not installed
        fi
}
for i in gcc cpp g++ gcov gccbug ; do 
        set_default $i $1
done
```

If you 1) name this script `switch-gcc`, 2) put it in your path, and 3) make it executable (`chmod +x switch-gcc`), you can then switch compiler versions just by running

`sudo switch-gcc 3.2`

Further reading on `update-alternatives`:

- https://lektiondestages.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-and-switching-gccg-versions.html
- https://codeyarns.com/2015/02/26/how-to-switch-gcc-version-using-update-alternatives/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version

Comment: `update-alternatives` is a debian/ubuntu thing afaik, not a general linux utility. Some distros use other means of selecting versions of tooling in a similar way though, but it depends on which distro you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find where the writeable strings are actually being used, another possibility would be to use [strdup](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) and [free](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html) on the subset of literal strings that the code is actually editing. This might be more complicated than downgrading versions of GCC, but will make the code much more portable.

**Edit**
In response to the clarification question / comment below, if you saw something like:

```
char* str = "XXX";
str[1] = 'Y';
str[2] = 'Z';
// ... use of str ...
```

You would replace the above with something like:

```
char* str = strdup("XXX");
str[1] = 'Y';
str[2] = 'Z';
// ... use of str ...
free(str);
```

And where you previously had:

```
char* str = "Some string that isn't modified";
```

You would replace the above with:

```
const char* str = "Some string that isn't modified";
```

Assuming you made these fixes, "-fwritable-strings" would no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just give the whole path of the gcc-3.4 install while compiling your program:
/path_to_gcc_3.4/gcc your_program

Comment: It's not my program. I'm using make.

Comment: Try to add this line to the Makefile: CC=/path_to_gcc_3.4/gcc