# Installing pycuda-2013.1.1 on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, pycuda

FYI, I have 64 bit version of Python 2.7 and
I followed [the pycuda installation instruction](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Windows) to install pycuda.

And I don't have any problem running following script.

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy
a = numpy.random.randn(4,4)
a = a.astype(numpy.float32)
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu,a)
```

But after that, when executing this statement,

```
mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void doublify(float *a)
{
int idx = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * 4;
a[idx] *= 2;
}
""")
```

I got the error messages

> CompileError: nvcc compilation of
>   c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\temp\tmpaoxt97\kernel.cu failed
>   [command: nvcc --cubin -arch sm_21 -m64
>   -Ic:\python27\lib\site-packages\pycuda\cuda kernel.cu] [stderr: nvcc : fatal error : nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft Visual
>   Studio. Only the versions 2008, 2010, and 2012 are supported

But I have VS 2008 and VS 2010 installed on the machine and set path and nvcc profile as instructed. Anybody tell me what's going on?

**UPDATE1**: As cgohike pointed out, running following statements before the problematic statement will solve the problem.

```
import os
os.system("vcvarsamd64.bat")
```

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2008 or higher installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64` or `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64` before `python.exe`. That will set all the necessary environment variables to use the 64 bit Visual Studio compiler from Python or the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it was too early to call it final. Even with resolution from cgohike, I got the same error when I ran other script like this

```
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy
a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(numpy.random.randn(4, 4))
print "a_gpu ="
print a_gpu
a_doubled = (2*a_gpu).get()
print
print "a_doubled ="
print a_doubled
```

And then I found [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14196802/749973) So in my case, I added following line in nvcc.profile

```
COMPILER-BINDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64
```

After this, no more compiler error I got. Hope it helps others.

Comment: How to edit the nvcc.profile ? In my case it doesnt allow rewriting this file at all. I tried editing it after I copied the file in another folder other  than the C:\Program files location and then pasting it again in the C:\Program files. When it gets saved over the line entered disappears. Do you by any chance know anything about this ?