# Pycuda compilation error stderr message unreadable

Tags: python, pycuda

My system is as follows:

System Environment:

Windows 7 Professional

anaconda 3 python 3.5.4

GPU: Quadr K2200 
driver: 353.90
CUDA toolkit: 7.5
Visual studio: Visual studio community 2013 (Japanese version) 
pycuda binary file that I used for installation: pycuda-2016.1.2+cuda7518-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycuda)

Added PATH variables as instructed from here: https://github.com/drasmuss/hessianfree/wiki/PyCUDA-installation-on-Windows

Additionally modified the nvcc.profile as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19039177/7428707

Then tried to run the hello_gpu example code from here: https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/

Got the following error:
[image]

The stderr message's formatting is not right. So I am unable to find out what the actual error is. I know there are a few related questions on here about this compilation error ( none of them have been answered, is there a solution at all ?) but the formatting problem in stderr has not been reported.

So my question is : How do I see the stderr content ? 
In general, is there a solution for this compilation error ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1167662/why-is-windows-10-displaying-as-%C2%A5-on-the-command-line/1167665 -- nothing to do with CUDA or Python, in all likelihood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasnt able to spend time on getting the stderr message to display. However I was able to solve the Compilation error message. 
I had to reconfigure the system a little.

```
Anaconda: 5.0.1 with python 3.6.3
Cuda Toolkit: CUDA 8.0  
Driver:376.51 for Quadro K2200
Visual Studio: Visual Studio community 2015 (custom installation: Visual C++ and Windows 10 SDK packages alone)
```

Added the

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
```

in Path environment variable.

Then created a new environment variable Include as follows:

```
setx /M INCLUDE C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
```

Then in Anaconda command prompt, I changed the encoding to utf-8 ( default was Shift-JIS since my OS was japanese)

```
chcp 65001
```

Then installed pycuda using pip

```
pip install pycuda
```

Installation was succesful and I was able to run the hello_gpu.py test code. However the nvcc compiler showed dozens of C4819 warnings (decoding warning because shift-JIS and utf-8 confusion) So I disabled the C4819 warning using the nvcc compiler command

```
nvcc -Xcompiler "/wd 4819"
```

references: [pycuda installation guide](https://qiita.com/ryo-yamaoka/items/5e09c2f2f0a24fce3282).[Clear pip installation UnicodeDecodeerror](https://qiita.com/akabei/items/da70ebf61cc413d5ff0d).[Hiding C4819 warning](https://qiita.com/aokomoriuta/items/b2c466b966714a7d5b9a)
All the references are in Japanese but I am giving them here in the hope they might help someone in similar situation as me.