# Compiling with different GCC versions

Tags: gcc, cuda

This is a follow up Q to [CUDA incompatible with my gcc version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version).
I've recently updated to Ubuntu 12.04 as well as grabbing the latest CUDA toolkit.  My `nvcc --version` is showing: `Cuda compilation tools, release 5.0`  (My driver ver is 304.43.)

I'm trying to fix my build environment.  I get errs about using GCC 4.6.  I can probably fix this w/ the help of the above link.  I'm wondering about the other 8 packages in this large project.  Should I be concerned with building other pieces with one version of GCC-4.6 and my cuda stuff with GCC-4.5?  I figure they should all be compatible, but I've never run into this before.  Is this anything I need to be concerned with?

Comment: Can't you just build the entire project with GCC-4.5? It seems like that would be a quick and probably harmless solution unless you need a specific feature of 4.6, which seems doubtful.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into incompatibility issues with different versions of GCC.

Specifically, GCC 4.7 and 4.6. My Qt applications wouldn't compile for me, because I was using GCC 4.7, and the library was compiled against GCC 4.6. They compiled fine, and there seemed to be no problem at first. But then I ran into trouble actually running them.

I would recommend against using different versions of GCC in the same project.