# CUDA - can't compile .cu files because of "gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp" error

Tags: gcc, cuda

I'm trying to compile a simple .cu file with CUDA 5 and gcc 4.7.3 on Ubuntu 13.0 but I'm getting

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You do not have a valid C++ compiler installed. Install g++ and the problem will go away.

Comment: Try `apt-get install g++`

Comment: Make it an answer and I'll accept it. You're correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have a valid C++ compiler installed. Install g++ and the problem will go away - `nvcc` requires a working, [supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6622751/681865) C++ host compiler to compile both device and host code.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem. And I checked my g++ it works well.
Finally I found the problem and solved it, I hope I can help those who have the same problem.

If you do not has g++ installed, try install it.

If you had a valid g++ and problem still exists, try two command respectively

```
gcc --version
g++ --version
```

If the output gcc version is different, that is the problem.

In my case the version of gcc is 7.4, g++ is 5.5. I want to use 7.4 so I run those command:

```
cd /usr/bin/
sudo rm gcc
sudo rm g++
sudo ln -s gcc-7 gcc
sudo ln -s g++-7 g++
```

And the problem disappeared.

If you want to use other versions, just change '7' to the version you want (may be '5').

Comment: You can use 
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 8`
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8 8` for example to fix this