# CUDA version X complains about not supporting gcc version Y - what to do?

Tags: gcc, cuda, compatibility

<sub>The question is about a specific combination of versions but is relevant more generally.</sub>

I've just dist-upgraded from Kubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. Now, when I want to compile CUDA code (with CUDA 6.5), I get:

```
#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc 4.9 and up are not supported!
```

I installed gcc-4.8 (and 4.7), and tried to use the symlinks-in-`/usr/local/cuda/bin` solution suggested here:

[CUDA incompatible with my gcc version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version)

but this doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<sub>This solution is relevant to multiple combinations of CUDA and GCC versions.</sub>

---

You can tell CUDA's `nvcc` to use a specific version of gcc. So, suppose you want gcc 4.7 for use with CUDA 6. You run:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7 g++-4.7
```

and then add the following switch to your `nvcc` command-line:

```
nvcc --compiler-bindir /usr/bin/gcc-4.7  # rest of the command line here
```

If you're building with CMake, add an appropriate setting before looking for CUDA to your `CMakeLists.txt`, e.g.:

```
set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc-4.7)  # -> ADD THIS LINE <-
find_package(CUDA)
```

Also, it seems clang can compile CUDA as well, maybe that's worth experimenting with (although you would have to build it appropriately).

**Note:** Some Linux (or other OS) distributions don't have packages for multiple versions of gcc (in the same release of the OS distribution). I would advise against trying to install a package from another release of the distribution on an older release, and consider building gcc instead. That's not entirely trivial but it is [quite doable](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) - and of course, it's your only option if you don't have root access to your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Switch back to a supported config.  They are listed in the getting started document for any recent CUDA distribution.

For your particular configuration you have currently listed, you might have better luck with CUDA 7 RC, which is now available to registered developers.

Comment: I can't remove gcc 4.9 from my system, or downgrade the distro for something as minor as this...

Comment: I switched to 7 which is really working well and it has support for 4.9. Though you might need to update to ubuntu 14.10. Also it has c++11 which is great.

Answer (score 1):

Very often you will find that CUDA has had [newer releases](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) by the time you encounter this problem. For example, the original formulation of the question was about CUDA 6 and GCC 4.9; CUDA 7 supported GCC 4.9. CUDA 8 supports GCC 5.x . And so on.

Comment: I have Cuda7.5 and got the same error as question for Caffe!

Comment: Quite unlikely. Perhaps you got a similar error for a newer version of gcc? CUDA 7.5 supports gcc 4.9, but does not support gcc 5.x

Comment: Well, I had GCC 5.x and was trying to say I have the same error

Comment: @MonaJalal: Time to upgrade to CUDA 8 then.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with CUDA Toolkit 7.5 and gcc 5.2.1.

I did modify the `host_config.h` file in `/usr/local/cuda/include/`:

Just remove the lines where it check the gcc version. It did solve my problem.

Credits goes to Darren Garvey (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/WaNmWZqMnzw)

Comment: There weren't any side affects that you saw from doing this, were there?

Comment: I didn't notice anything. Everything seems working fine

Comment: @Conchylicultor: There are multiple known incompatibilities between CUDA 7.x and GCC 5.x . It would be unwise to remove the version check.

Comment: @einpoklum Probably, I suppose they put this limit for a reason but this hack worked perfectly for me. Just out of curiosity, what are the incompatibilities for instance ?

Comment: Mysterious compilation failures with certain standard library constructs; weird linking trouble which I forget the details of since I didn't file a bug about them.