# CUDA 7.0 complains about not supporting gcc 4.9

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cuda, compatibility

I have installed gcc-4.7, gcc-4.8, gcc-4.9

When I try to do:

```
luarocks install cutorch
```

I get an error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:59:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/include/host_config.h:82:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc 4.9 and up are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc 4.9 and up are not supported!
```

I found a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009785/cuda-6-5-complains-about-not-supporting-gcc-4-9-what-to-do)

But when I try to run the command:

```
nvcc --compiler-bindir /usr/bin/gcc-4.7
```

I get an error:

```
nvcc fatal: No input files specified; use option --help for more information
```

I'm new and installed linux day ago. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following commands before the installation:

```
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.8
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.8
```

this should set the compiler to gcc-4.8 for the compilation.