# gcc versions later are not supported

Tags: gcc, gnu

I just set up a Ubuntu.
I'm trying to turn the yolo of darknet. and I've got this error.

```
/usr/local/cuda/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
```

Even I tried

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

I got

```
Package g++-4.9 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-4.9' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'g++-4.9' has no installation candidate
```

It seems that the version error occurs by downloading the recent version.
Do you know how to downgrade the gcc version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CUDA incompatible with my gcc version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

The Python version control was the cause.

It was resolved by re-establishing and reinstalling the paths of the packages.

Comment: Do you mean you have upgrade the Python version? Which version works at the end? Thanks!!