# CMake: unsupported GNU version -- gcc versions later than 8 are not supported

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, cmake

Before downgrading my GCC, I want to know if there's a way to figure which programs/frameworks or dependencies in my machine will break and if there is a better way to do this for openpose installation? (e.g. changing something in CMake)

Is there a hack to fix this without changing my system GCC version and potentially breaking other things?

```
[10889:10881 0:2009] 09:21:36 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~/research/code/openpose/build
$ make -j`nproc`
[ 12%] Performing configure step for 'openpose_lib'
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/Misc.cmake:32 (set):
  implicitly converting 'BOOLEAN' to 'STRING' type.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:25 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so)
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so)
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/local/bin/protoc
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine CXX configuration
-- CUDA detected: 10.1
-- Added CUDA NVCC flags for: sm_75
-- Found Atlas: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu  
-- Found Atlas (include: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatlas.so lapack: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so
-- Python interface is disabled or not all required dependencies found. Building without it...
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.25.1") 
-- 
-- ******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
-- General:
--   Version           :   1.0.0
--   Git               :   1.0-149-g1807aada
--   System            :   Linux
--   C++ compiler      :   /usr/bin/c++
--   Release CXX flags :   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Debug CXX flags   :   -g -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Build type        :   Release
-- 
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   ON
--   BUILD_python      :   OFF
--   BUILD_matlab      :   OFF
--   BUILD_docs        :   OFF
--   CPU_ONLY          :   OFF
--   USE_OPENCV        :   OFF
--   USE_LEVELDB       :   OFF
--   USE_LMDB          :   OFF
--   USE_NCCL          :   OFF
--   ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK :   OFF
--   USE_HDF5          :   ON
-- 
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (Atlas)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.71)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 3.6.1)
--   CUDA              :   Yes (ver. 10.1)
-- 
-- NVIDIA CUDA:
--   Target GPU(s)     :   Auto
--   GPU arch(s)       :   sm_75
--   cuDNN             :   Disabled
-- 
-- Install:
--   Install path      :   /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CUDA_ARCH_BIN


-- Build files have been written to: /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build
[ 25%] Performing build step for 'openpose_lib'
[  1%] Running C++/Python protocol buffer compiler on /home/mona/research/code/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
Scanning dependencies of target caffeproto
[  1%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffeproto.dir/__/__/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc.o
[  1%] Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libcaffeproto.a
[  1%] Built target caffeproto
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/util/cuda_compile_1_generated_math_functions.cu.o
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_bnll_layer.cu.o
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_accuracy_layer.cu.o
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_reindex_layer.cu.o
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_norm_layer.cu.o
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_bias_layer.cu.o
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_base_data_layer.cu.o
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_concat_layer.cu.o
[  5%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_clip_layer.cu.o
[  6%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_absval_layer.cu.o
[  6%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_conv_layer.cu.o
[  6%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_contrastive_loss_layer.cu.o
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /home/mona/research/code/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/src/caffe/util/math_functions.cu:1:
/usr/include/math_functions.h:54:2: warning: #warning "math_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.  Please use cuda_runtime_api.h or cuda_runtime.h instead." [-Wcpp]
   54 | #warning "math_functions.h is an internal header file and must not be used directly.  This file will be removed in a future CUDA release.  Please use cuda_runtime_api.h or cuda_runtime.h instead."
      |  ^~~~~~~
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_clip_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_clip_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:114: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_clip_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_absval_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_absval_layer.cu.o


CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_concat_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_concat_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:65: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_absval_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:121: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_concat_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_reindex_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_reindex_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:93: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_reindex_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_bias_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_bias_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:100: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_bias_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_norm_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_norm_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:86: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_norm_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_contrastive_loss_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_contrastive_loss_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:128: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_contrastive_loss_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_conv_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_conv_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:135: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_conv_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_accuracy_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_accuracy_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:72: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_accuracy_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_base_data_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_base_data_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:79: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_base_data_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_bnll_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_bnll_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:107: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_bnll_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_math_functions.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/util/./cuda_compile_1_generated_math_functions.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:499: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/util/cuda_compile_1_generated_math_functions.cu.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:371: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/build.make:112: caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
21834/31772MB(openpose) 
[10889:10881 0:2010] 09:21:55 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~/research/code/openpose/build
$
```

I have:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I am following the compilation instructions here on Ubuntu 20.04:
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation/README.md#prerequisites

Comment: You're probably better off removing that `#error` directive and seeing what needs to be fixed or trying clang than downgrading GCC.

Comment: @bk2204 thanks for your prompt response. This is not my code. Could you explain how I should go about that?

Comment: Since it looks like that code comes from `/usr/include/crt/host_config.h`, you might want to upgrade the package that provides that header.  I don't know what package that is, since it's not present on my system.  If you want to try using clang, you can set `CC=clang` and `CXX=clang++`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solved by downgrading the GCC from 9.3.0 to 7:

```
$ sudo apt remove gcc
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7 -y
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-7 /usr/bin/gcc
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-7 /usr/bin/g++
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-7 /usr/bin/cc
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-7 /usr/bin/c++
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Why 7 and not 8?

Comment: Because https://stackoverflow.com/a/46380601/667127 @der_michael

Answer (score 8):

You should point to a correct GCC bin file (below 9) from the dependencies in cmake command. no need to downgrade the GCC for example:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-8
```

Comment: Is this the same with change symlink? Mine is like `/usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-7`

Comment: Instead of downgrading, its better to just give path of gcc-8. Thanks.