# How to build qemu with a specific gcc version?

Tags: gcc, gnu-make, autotools, configure, qemu

I am trying to build a past version of qemu, and I wish to do it using a specific version of gcc. How could I go about doing this?

To be more specific, I am trying to build qemu using gcc-4.9.2, and I tried to use the info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698441/how-to-use-an-older-version-of-gcc-in-linux), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configure` has a specific option that I had not noticed, and after installing the appropriate gcc, I simply used that option: `--cc=gcc-4.9`.