# RestBed - Not able to compile in Redhat 7

Tags: c++, restbed

We are building our C++ application in RHEL7 and we need to use RestBed as a service and as a client.

However, when tried to compile the source code, we are getting error on GCC that the version is < 4.9.

RedHat dont support GCC version > 4.8.5.

So, what is the solution? Do we have a branch which works with GCC 4.8.5?

EDIT:
The "configuration.cmake" has the below lines of code.

```
if ( ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL GNU )
    if ( ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 4.9 )
        message( FATAL_ERROR "\nGCC version < 4.9\nYour systems default compiler is GCC. This project makes use of c++11 features present only in versions of gcc >= 4.9. You can use a different compiler by re-running cmake with the command switch \"-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=<compiler>\" " )
    else ( )
        set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-non-virtual-dtor" )
    endif ( )
```

So, the code wont support the version by default I guess.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698441/how-to-use-an-older-version-of-gcc-in-linux

Comment: Well, that didnt help, since compilation is not supporting such flags. I have edited and added the code snippet which checks for the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restbed requires a compiler that supports C++11, with all the trimmings.

Comment: ok, thank you for the confirmation, we are using the devtool to fix this. please notify us, in case you decide to give a fix.

Comment: We've removed the specific compiler checking and replaced it with CMake CXX_Standard detection.  It might now compile but you may experience undefined behavior if your compiler has only partial C++11 support.

Comment: Wow, thank you for giving this feature. We will check and update you, really appreciate the support.

Comment: Not at all.  What is Software if we can't all use it?   That being said, no guarantees it will function correctly without C++11 compliance.